# Swift iOS NSDictionary setValue crash - but why?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have this code (porting from another language, hence a bit different naming conventions, but please bear with this for now)

```
var FDefaultsList: NSDictionary = [String:String]();
let TmpKey: String = TmpKeyValue[0];
let TmpValue: String = TmpKeyValue[1];    
if (TmpKey != "") && (TmpValue != "") {
  //let TmpAnyObjectValue: AnyObject? = TmpValue;
  //FDefaultsList.setValue(TmpAnyObjectValue, forKey: TmpKey);
  FDefaultsList.setValue(TmpValue, forKey: TmpKey);
}
```

However, no matter the which setValue variation I use, the call to setValue throws an error (not meaningful as far as I can tell) and exits app (Xcode editor is taken to **class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate**)

I guess I am using NSDictionary wrong? I am trying to read in a text file where each line is key=value strings

Comment: use FDefaultsList[TmpValue] = TmpKey & only use Dictionary from swift not NSDictionary.

Comment: you should include the error message even if it means nothing to you. use `setObject` instead of `setValue` and it should be an `NSMutableDictionary` if you want to edit it

Comment: I want a (mutable) dictionary where I can read/write string keys/values. I will try to read up on pros/cons of cocoa/obj-c dictionary (?) versus swift dictionary.

Comment: @Tom swift Dictionary is mutable, you just need to define it as `var` not `let`

Comment: Basically never use `setValue:forKey:` unless you really need KVC. To set a `value` for `key` use  always `setObject:forKey:` or key subscripting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should declare an actual NSMutableDictionary instead of casting to NSDictionary.

And you can use subscript which a bit simpler to use than `setValue` (which should actually be `setObject`):

```
var FDefaultsList = NSMutableDictionary()
let TmpKey: String = "a"
let TmpValue: String = "b"
if TmpKey != "" && TmpValue != "" {
    FDefaultsList[TmpValue] = TmpKey
}
```

A more "Swifty" version could be:

```
var defaultsList = [String:String]()
let tmpKey = "a"
let tmpValue = "b"
if !tmpKey.isEmpty && !tmpValue.isEmpty {
    defaultsList[tmpValue] = tmpKey
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works now :)